# Manifest merging failed

Tags: android

Added dependencies

```
/*for clevertap*/
    implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.6.4'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

then while running the project in device got

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-46:19 to override.
```

Comment: have u tried  tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" in manifest's application  tag

Comment: tried but not worked

Comment: you have to migrate the project to AndroidX

Comment: post your manifest and gradle(app) code

Answer (score -1):

Just add below code in your project Manifest application tag.

```
<application
        tools:node="replace">
```